# Query all rows from Mysql table and store as cache

Tags: mysql, go

I have one table required to do some charging in my application. I am trying to load this table in a JSON struct and use it as a cache. This is my approach:

table:

```
CREATE TABLE `lwratecarddefinition` (
  `RATECARDID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RATECARDGROUPID`   int(10)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERVICEID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USAGETYPEID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CURRENCYCODE` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LEDGERID` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PULSE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SPECIALPULSE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NORMALRATE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OFFPEAKSET` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OFFPEAKRATE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PEAKRATE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ONDEMANDSET` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ONDEMANDRATE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `idx_lwratecarddefinition_RATECARDID` (`RATECARDID`),
   KEY `idx_lwratecarddefinition_RATECARDGROUPID` (`RATECARDGROUPID`),
   KEY `idx_lwratecarddefinition_USAGETYPEID` (`USAGETYPEID`),
   KEY `idx_lwratecarddefinition_SERVICEID` (`SERVICEID`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

main.go code snippet - ( my objective is to fetch records in every 1 min using go routine )

```
    // load the ratecard first
    lwratecardefinition = getRatecard()
    // update data every 1 second
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            lwratecardefinition = getRatecard()
            fmt.Println(lwratecardefinition)
            }
    }()
```

dbfunction.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Lwratecardefinition struct {
        Ratecardid        int    `json:"ratecardid"`
        Ratecardgroupid   int    `json:"ratecardgroupid"`
        Serviceid         int    `json:"serviceid"`
        Usagetypeid       int    `json:"usagetypeid"`
        Currencycode      int    `json:"currencycode"`
        Ledgerid          string `json:"ledgerid"`
        Pulse             int    `json:"pulse"`
        Specialpulse      int    `json:"specialpulse"`
        Normalrate        int    `json:"normalrate"`
        Offpeakset        int    `json:"offpeakset"`
        Offpeakrate       int    `json:"offpeakrate"`
        Peakrate          int    `json:"peakrate"`
        Ondemandset       int    `json:"ondemandset"`
        Ondemandrate      int    `json:"ondemandrate"`
}

var lwratecardefinition Lwratecardefinition
func getRatecard() Lwratecardefinition {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/bcsdb")

    // if there is an error opening the connection, handle it
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // defer the close till after the main function has finished
    // executing
    defer db.Close()

var ratecardid,ratecardgroupid,serviceid,usagetypeid,currencycode,pulse,specialpulse,normalrate,offpeakset,offpeakrate,peakrate,ondemandset,ondemandrate int
var ledgerid string

    results, err := db.Query("select ratecardid,ratecardgroupid,serviceid,usagetypeid,currencycode,ledgerid,pulse,specialpulse,normalrate,offpeakset,offpeakrate,peakrate,ondemandset,ondemandrate from lwratecarddefinition")

     if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for results.Next() {
     err = results.Scan(&ratecardid,&ratecardgroupid,&serviceid,&usagetypeid,&currencycode,&ledgerid,&pulse,&specialpulse,&normalrate,&offpeakset,&offpeakrate,&peakrate,&ondemandset,&ondemandrate)

lwratecardefinition = Lwratecardefinition{Ratecardid: ratecardid, Ratecardgroupid: ratecardgroupid, Serviceid: serviceid, Usagetypeid: usagetypeid, Currencycode: currencycode, Ledgerid: ledgerid, Pulse: pulse, Specialpulse: specialpulse, Normalrate: normalrate, Offpeakset: offpeakset, Offpeakrate: offpeakrate, Peakrate: peakrate, Ondemandset: ondemandset, Ondemandrate: ondemandrate}

}
return lwratecardefinition
}
```

But when I am executing the program I am only getting one row not all rows from mysql table. I need all rows to use it as a cache.
output:

```
{4 508 1 201 1 DATA 60 30 2 1 3 1 1 5}
```

Also my final objective is to use these values to find rate and pulse.If
 Ratecardgroupid  = X value and Serviceid = Y value I want to use pulse value from same row.
Please suggest what is wrong here and if the approach is fine to reduce db calls as well logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I am executing the program I am only getting one row not all rows from mysql table

Because your function only returns single `Lwratecardefinition` struct, value of which you override in each iteration of the loop. You want to return slice of them, something like:

```
func getRatecard() []Lwratecardefinition {
   ...
   var result []Lwratecardefinition
   for results.Next() {
     err = results.Scan(&ratecardid,&ratecardgroupid,&serviceid,&usagetypeid,&currencycode,&ledgerid,&pulse,&specialpulse,&normalrate,&offpeakset,&offpeakrate,&peakrate,&ondemandset,&ondemandrate)
     result = append(result, Lwratecardefinition{Ratecardid: ratecardid, Ratecardgroupid: ratecardgroupid, Serviceid: serviceid, Usagetypeid: usagetypeid, Currencycode: currencycode, Ledgerid: ledgerid, Pulse: pulse, Specialpulse: specialpulse, Normalrate: normalrate, Offpeakset: offpeakset, Offpeakrate: offpeakrate, Peakrate: peakrate, Ondemandset: ondemandset, Ondemandrate: ondemandrate})
   }

   if (results.Err() != nil) {
      // something went wrong while reading records
      ...
   }
   return result
}
```